# Bash with while, for and if works, until I add a second value

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop, jq

I have a script where I extract values from curl statements using jq. This script works well whenever the if-statement receives one true value, however, it breaks as soon as a second media package is found and has to be processed.

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash

source mh_auth.sh

rm -f times.txt
touch times.txt

#Read lines from file with mediapackage-id's that are on schedule.
while read LINE; do


        curl --silent --digest -u $mh_username:$mh_password -H "X-Requested-Auth: Digest" -H "X-Opencast-Matterhorn-Authorization: true" "$mh_server/workflow/instances.json?mp=$LINE" >  $LINE-curl.txt

        #Format the file to make it more readable if you need to troubleshoot
        /usr/bin/python -m json.tool $LINE-curl.txt > $LINE-curl-final.txt

        #Test to see if this mediapackage has been published yet, and if it has, extract the necessary values for calculation

        if grep -q -e 'Cleaning up"' $LINE-curl-final.txt; then

                echo "Media Package found"
                workflows=$( jq '.workflows.workflow[]' < $LINE-curl-final.txt )

                for i in "${workflows}"
                do
                        echo "Getting the end_time variable"
                        end_time=`echo ${i} | jq '.operations.operation[] | select(.description == "Cleaning up") | .completed'`
                        echo "Done getting end time variable"
                        echo "Getting ingest time variable"
                        ingest_time=`echo ${i} | jq '.operations.operation[] | select(.description == "Ingest") | .completed'`
                        echo "Done getting ingest time variable"

                        echo $ingest_time  $end_time  >> times.txt
                        echo last >> times.txt

                done

        else
                echo "Media Package not published yet"
        fi

        rm -f $LINE-curl.txt
        rm -f $LINE-curl-final.txt

done < scheduled-mediapackages.txt
```

A successful run yields the following:

```
Media Package not published yet
Media Package not published yet
Media Package not published yet
Media Package not published yet
Media Package not published yet
Media Package not published yet
Media Package not published yet
Media Package not published yet
Media Package not published yet
Media Package not published yet
Media Package found
Getting the end_time variable
Done getting end time variable
Getting ingest time variable
Done getting ingest time variable
```

Whenever I add a second published media package containing exactly the same json as the first to my list, I get the following:

```
Media Package not published yet
Media Package not published yet
Media Package found
Getting the end_time variable
Done getting end time variable
Getting ingest time variable
Done getting ingest time variable
Media Package found
Getting the end_time variable
jq: error: Cannot index string with string
jq: error: Cannot index string with string
jq: error: Cannot index string with string
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
jq: error: Cannot index string with string
jq: error: Cannot index string with string
jq: error: Cannot index string with string
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
Done getting end time variable
Getting ingest time variable
jq: error: Cannot index string with string
jq: error: Cannot index string with string
jq: error: Cannot index string with string
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
jq: error: Cannot index string with string
jq: error: Cannot index string with string
jq: error: Cannot index string with string
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
Done getting ingest time variable
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I have been going around in circles and cannot get it to work?

Comment: Try removing the double quotes from the `for i in $workflows`

Comment: Or maybe `workflows` is meant to be an array? In which case you probably need to create it like this: `IFS=$'\n' workflows=( $(jq...) )`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for response! I get the following if use your second comment's declaration: `Media Package not published yet
Media Package found
Getting the end_time variable
parse error: Unfinished JSON term
Done getting end time variable
Getting ingest time variable
parse error: Unfinished JSON term
Done getting ingest time variable
Media Package found
Getting the end_time variable
jq: error: Cannot index string with string
Done getting end time variable
Getting ingest time variable
jq: error: Cannot index string with string
Done getting ingest time variable
` Any ideas?

Comment: As I said earlier, it works perfectly well with one file, and to my knowledge the `workflows` array should be "destroyed" when the if-statement is done on a specific file. The idea is create file with json info -> run the extraction of info -> delete file and get next mediapackage in list -> create file... etc. So the `workflows` array should be created from scratch for each file. Or am I missing something?

Comment: All I was saying is that `for i in "$workflows" is likely to be wrong because the double quotes kind of `hold the contents of $workflows together` into a single entity so that will not be a good thing to iterate over because there is only one entity.

Comment: So I guessed you maybe meant an array and suggested how to initialise that. Try changing the first line to `#!/bin/bash -xv` and running again and you will see a load of debug info as the script runs.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I understand, thanks! I tried to remove them, but get a MOUNTAIN of errors if I do that. But because I write separate files for each media package, it maybe isn't necessary to do a for loop?

Comment: @BashNewbie, you should remove all the extraneous stuff from your code example. Come up with a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it might seem arrogant to answer my own question, but for all those out there who has struggled like me, I wanted to add a fix. Before I get any slams for the code maybe being clumsy and "too much", just remember, I just started coding in bash, and this is working. Others might find this and with their experience be able to clean it up. For me though, this is what worked, so I stuck with it.

Thanks to Mark Setchell, I went back to the drawing board to figure out why the while loop was giving me a hard time. I figured out that some of the json return I got had more objects in it than others, so the jq command had to be adjusted to fit each command. I am only posting the relevant code for extracting the data I was looking for in my OP.

```
if grep -q -e 'Cleaning up"' $LINE-curl-final.txt; then
```

Because some media packages fail on first processing, then gets "picked up" to be re-processed, they have more than one workflow object. This if-statement searches for the succeeded one between them,and extracts the data with the adjusted jq query

```
get_count=$( jq -r '.[] | .totalCount' < $LINE-curl-final.txt )                
    if  [[ "$get_count" -gt 1 ]]; then

       state=$( jq -r '.workflows.workflow[] | select(.state == "SUCCEEDED" ) | .operations.operation[] | select(.description == "Cleaning up") | .state' < $LINE-curl-final.txt )

       if [ "$state" = "SUCCEEDED" ];then

           end_time=$( jq '.workflows.workflow[] | select(.state == "SUCCEEDED" ) | .operations.operation[] | select(.description == "Cleaning up") | .completed' < $LINE-curl-final.txt )
           ingest_time=$( jq '.workflows.workflow [] | .operations.operation[] | select(.description == "Ingest") | .completed' < $LINE-curl-final.txt )

       fi

   else
       state=$(  jq -r '.workflows.workflow.operations.operation[] | select(.description == "Cleaning up") | .state' < $LINE-curl-final.txt )
       if [ "$state" = "SUCCEEDED" ];then

           end_time=$( jq '.workflows.workflow.operations.operation[] | select(.description == "Cleaning up") | .completed' < $LINE-curl-final.txt )
           ingest_time=$( jq '.workflows.workflow.operations.operation[] | select(.description == "Ingest") | .completed' < $LINE-curl-final.txt )

       fi

    fi
```

Note the difference between

```
jq '.workflows.workflow.operations.operation[] | select(.description == "Cleaning up") | .completed'
```

and

```
jq '.workflows.workflow[] | select(.state == "SUCCEEDED" ) | .operations.operation[] | select(.description == "Cleaning up") | .completed'
```

I hope that this idea might help anybody else struggling with the same problem.